# Xamarin iOS Crashlytics DSYM file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working in Xamarin iOS project and I have integrated Crashlytics into my project. I am able to see if a crash occurs in app on Firebase console.

I am building my solution on release configuration and I am getting this message:

> './upload-symbols' -gsp './GoogleService-Info.plist' -p ios
> './bin/iPhone//MyApp.app.dSYM' 4>  Successfully submitted symbols for
> architecture armv7 with UUID 5eefaf6e77ea3cacbf3a64ec5adaf364 in dSYM:
> /Users/mac/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp/f30525a554015a02acqa0a8e602c1f02/bin/iPhone/MyApp.app.dSYM[0m
> 4>  Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID
> 7cde4d6c986f3bd58f4d1acaf1f81591 in dSYM:
> /Users/mac/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp/f3052aca55405a02a7ea0a8e602c1f02/bin/iPhone/MyApp.app.dSYM[0m
> 4>  [32mSuccessfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols[0m

But still in my Firebase Crashlytics console i see "missing 2 dsym files" error

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0#upload-dsyms

Comment: @MihailDuchev I still dont understand where I can find this script?

Comment: This was a pain for me. I had to use my mac build host and setup a test xcode project. Installed cocoapods, added crashlytics to the podfile and ran the "install". After that I copied the dsyms and googleservice-into.plist to my mac, ran the upload-sybols scripts and it worked.

Comment: @Behr Is this the expected way to do it? Should it be automatic?

Comment: @Waleed are you starting the app in the Release Solution configuration?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez I don't think it was ever automatic for Xamarin. I use to upload them directly to google crashlytics, but they no longer allow that. The only way I found was the way I mentioned before.

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez My mistake, it looks like the latest crashlytics for Xamarin does auto upload them. Be sure you are on the latest NuGet package.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check

Answer (score 0):

Check out the folder:

C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\FCrshlytcs-3.14.0\iOS\Crashlytics.framework

upload-symbols program is in there.

The whole thing should be automated though with the latest Crashlytics NuGet package.